# Error in parsing value for 'background-position'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to animate my menu. But nothing happens, I only receive the following error in the console: "Error in parsing value for 'background-position'".

Can you please help me?

CSS:

```
nav li a {
            display:block;
            height:96px;
            width:124px;
            color:#818080;
            text-align:center;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding-top:60px;
            background:url(../img/n1-hover.gif) 0 -146px no-repeat;
        }
```

JavaScript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {                    
        $('.menu a').hover(
        function(){$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'}, 800, 'easeOutBounce')}, 
        function(){$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'0px -146px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce')});  
    });
```

I forgot to mention, that I'm using the plugin [JQuery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

Comment: animating during the ready event is not good, cause the page is not done loading, and it will be a broken animation. try the onload event.

Comment: Actually, by definition, the page is done loading when the ready event handler is called.

kavuch, you don't indicate which browser you are using. This probably makes a difference, especially if the problem is, as some of the answers indicate, the use of "0px."

Note that in CSS, 0 is *never* followed by px or pt or em or % or any other unit specifier.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, but it wouldn't be bad, if this ran in the most modern Browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `px` part from backgroun position it should work fine. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {                    
                $('.menu a').hover(
                function(){$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'0 0'}, 800, 'easeOutBounce')}, 
                function(){$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'0 -146'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce')});  
            });
```